# loop through results returned from database query to then run individual api calls against individual items retreived from database query in Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, tweepy

Ok, so I have done a bunch of searching, but I think I am just banging me head against the wall. I'm having a bear of a time trying to figure this problem out, but here is what I am trying to do:

### Program Overview

I am using `tweepy` to gather a bunch of tweets from a particular target user. Those values are stored in a `MySQL` database. I am storing the tweets themselves, and the tweet ID (status_id in the context of the API) so I have something to mine for later. In the context of this program, I am trying a list of users that have retweeted a particular tweet, and eventually create a list of a particular twitter user's "Top *whatever* Re-Tweeters." I have the ingestion portion of the target tweets problem solved, that information gets logged into the database without any issues.

### Where I'm running into problems

When I query the database for the list of the tweet ID's to look up against the api for who retweeted which of those main tweets, I have issues with trying to loop through how the data comes out of the database query. Query comes out as tuples, and when I try to loop through them in a `for` loop, the API gets angry and kicks back:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]
```

My best guess at this point is that I'm not looping through this right, or I am having some issues with data types.

#### My Code So Far

```
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
import json 
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import mysql.connector
import time

# Define Database Connectivity

cpalsDb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="vagrant",
  password="password",
  database="cpals"
)

# Authenticate to Twitter
consumer_key= '#######'
consumer_secret= '###########'
access_token= '###########'
access_token_secret= '#####################'
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


mycursorread = cpalsDb.cursor()
mycursorread.execute("SELECT tweetID FROM tweets")
myresult = mycursorread.fetchall()

def queryCleanup(singleColumnData):
    for x in singleColumnData:
        print("TWEET: ", x)
        print(type(x))
        for y in x:
            api.retweeters(y)
            print("Retweeters: ", y)
    return

queryCleanup(singleColumnData=myresult)
```

### Conclusion

My code is kind of a mess, and I am a hobbyist in Python, so loops still evade me, as does the general order of things.

Do I need separate loops? Am I just a fool? I'm essentially asking Python "Hey, pull this row from the database. For each item, tell me who retweeted that tweet, move onto the next.

Thank you in advance, I do appreciate it!

Comment: what error at what line is presented?

Comment: It was at line 47.

Comment: can you post the specific line here?

Comment: I honestly cannot tell what you're asking here. Can you try to very tightly summarize your question at the beginning, then allow the reader to get more context by reading all of the details?

Answer (score 0):

After messing around for a good long while, I managed to sort the issue out.

I changed the function to look like this:

```
def queryCleanup(singleColumnData):
    for x in singleColumnData:
        print("HEADTWEETS: ")
        print(x)
        for y in x:
            print("RETWEET USERS: ")
            retweetersList = api.retweeters(y)
            print(retweetersList)
     return
```

Called it like this:

```
queryCleanup(singleColumnData=myresult)
```

Which produced this output:

```
HEADTWEETS: 
(1377362181499482115,)
RETWEET USERS:
[517650988, 209633971, 2998940037, 557773370, 331270224, 482554207, 2530841186, 1236678962899824640, 27342363, 4134412067, 378132278, 289881627, 1014962042980225027, 2294193683, 147233205, 1156431, 1318958426744082432, 942782498932711424, 343431172, 560821229, 1317232193228464128, 178063571, 826619148, 936706135, 325340700, 840326004, 587987252, 
1068897042297208832, 115775544, 268810091, 185780563, 43137775, 479224989, 376937152, 36946774, 20952823, 1017105484678123526, 42400785, 23933931, 17428614, 2959876373, 39891241, 19277857, 47416273, 20458833, 478719002, 340770461, 1364297002016768009, 1195727038964879362, 1184079800, 741307184500219904, 83186542, 829432901439741952, 1480959499, 1290009503824568320, 3084709625, 1373237390152716288, 720819722787364864, 57443302, 489979941, 152252818, 209327707, 346107530, 384128700, 1077705300650614785, 419288157, 833776431528284161, 97000212, 30498849, 796894834002980864, 76444062, 39250142, 1271237346143416321, 60077913, 2815794381, 1356329370751791106, 31054493, 3025642511, 598757743, 1000154893200576512, 826903009884004352, 94908878, 1028095152940883968, 42491102, 999904518723653633, 2404795357, 1212825449958539264]
```

So now it loops through the Tweet ID of each tweet that i have in my database, then it produces all the retweet users of each individual tweet.

My full working example looks like this:

```
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
import json 
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import mysql.connector
import time

cpalsDb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="vagrant",
  password="password",
  database="cpals"
)

# Authenticate to Twitter
consumer_key= 
consumer_secret= 
access_token= 
access_token_secret= 
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Grab a list of tweets that we need to action through... 

mycursorread = cpalsDb.cursor()
mycursorread.execute("SELECT tweetID FROM tweets")
myresult = mycursorread.fetchall()
cpalsDb.commit()


def queryCleanup(singleColumnData):
    for x in singleColumnData:
        print("HEADTWEETS: ")
        print(x)
        for y in x:
            print("RETWEET USERS: ")
            retweetersList = api.retweeters(y)
            print(retweetersList)
    return

queryCleanup(singleColumnData=myresult)
```

My script has a way to go still, so it's still a *work in progress* - but thanks to everyone who looked at this!